# Connecting iOS a set of iOS devices with Wifi network

Tags: ios, sdk, wifi, synchronization, device

I'm searching a new way to sync data between iOS devices connected to the same Wi-fi network.

My app uses iCloud to sync its CoreData UIManagedDocument, but iCloud latency is too big for my goals.

Is there some way to connect iOS devices in the same Wi-Fi network with the iOS SDK? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gamekit to connect with both WiFi and Bluetooth and send data back and forth.

There's an excellent but lengthy tutorial here http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1
you should be able to pick out all the connectivity bits.

Answer (score 2):

Any two IP-capable devices can connect to each other using BSD sockets - I've written an Objective-C wrapper to facilitate networking operations like this - [here it is.](http://github.com/H2CO3/TCPHelper)

Comment: "Any two IP-capable devices can connect to each other using BSD sockets" yes, but I'm looking for some API inside iOS SDK. I'm try with Darren Link.
Thanks!

Comment: @Mandels the C standard library **is** part of the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 7, you should look into the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html). It allows connections between iOS devices on the same Wi-Fi network or Bluetooth personal area network, and the API is extremely simple to use.